# Django Rest Framework Default Settings Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm facing an issue with Django Rest Framework (DRF) where the default settings I've configured in my settings.py file are not working as expected. Specifically, I've set up default pagination and authentication classes, but they don't seem to be applied to my views.

I am using :

```
python3.11
Django==4.2.5
djangorestframework==3.14.0
django_filter==23.3
```

Here are the relevant parts of my project configuration:

```
settings.py:
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ]
}
```

```
project/urls.py
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

`myapp/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myview/', views.MyListView.as_view()),  # MyListView is a DRF view
]
```

`my app/views.py`

```
class MyListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be correct in the settings.py but you might be overriding them in your views.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style

If you set the pagination_class attribute of a generic view subclass, it won't use the default, it will use whatever you set it. Maybe you did that.

Comment: I have updated the question with the view. I didn't write the 'pagination_class' in my view. How can I confirm it is reading everything from settings.cpy?

Comment: @arunna what is myview/ returning when you request that path?

Comment: from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
print(api_settings.defaults['DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'])
print(api_settings.defaults['DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES'])


I added this line in my views.py and it is returning None for 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS' I think this is the issue

Comment: My endpoint return data from Author Model

Comment: what is the structure of the data that returns? why do you think it's not the right pagination?

api_settings.defaults is the defaults set by rest_framework. in order to access the setting the user(you) set, you use api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
api_settings.defaults['DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'] is supposed to be None.

Comment: [{"id": 2, "firstName": "Arun", "lastName": "N A",  "books": [] }, 
{"id": 3, "firstName": "ArunO", "lastName": "N A",  "books": []}
{"id": 4, "firstName": "ArunsO", "lastName": "N A",  "books": []}
]

I am getting full records from the Model

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @arunna a paginated result would look like this:
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/users/1/",
            "username": "apollo",
            "email": "",
            "is_staff": true
        }
    ]
}

you're not getting count, next, previous keys?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255404/discussion-between-arun-n-a-and-apollo).

Comment: I resolved it. The issues was with the settings.py, I have used ```import rest_framework.pagination``` that was the problem. Now it is working. Thanks for ur valuable time.